# How to print my Caesar cipher without spaces?

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to print them message from this program without spaces but it always gives me spaces between each letter.

```
import string
character = []
message = raw_input('What is your message? ').lower()
shift = raw_input('What is your shift key? ')
type = raw_input('Would you like to cipher(c) or decipher(d)? ')
for character in message:
    if str(type) == 'd':
        number = ord(character) - int(shift)
        if number <= 96:
            number = ord(character) + 26 - int(shift)
    if str(type) == 'c':
        number = ord(character) + int(shift)
        if number >= 122:
            number = ord(character) - 26 + int(shift)
    character = chr(number)
    print(character),
```

Does anyone know hot to print in a sentence so that I can copy the message and recipher it?

Comment: This question should probably drop the cryptography tag and add some language tag.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson with a 28k rep you should be able to edit that yourself (anyway, changed) (good additional answer btw).

Answer (score 2):

add

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to the top of your program and then change

```
print(character),
```

to

```
print(character, end='')
```

this is [explained here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

without the first line you are actually printing `(character)` which is an expression whose result is `character`, so it's basically `print character,`.  with the import, `print ...` changes to `print(...)` and takes extra arguments that give you more control.

note, this won't work on very old python versions.  you probably need 2.6 or later.

[hi scott!]

Answer (score 1):

Lose the comma at the end of the print statement.  Of course, then every character will be on a separate line.

Probably best to build up the characters into a string which can be printed all at once.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: Sure, but Andrew's idea is better.  Set a new variable before the loop, say `line = ""`; then replace your print with `line += character`; finally, after the loop, `print line`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.stdout.write(character)` to print individual characters without spaces or newlines much like C's `putchar`.

For example:

```
import string
import sys

character = []
message = raw_input('What is your message? ').lower()
shift = raw_input('What is your shift key? ')
type = raw_input('Would you like to cipher(c) or decipher(d)? ')
for character in message:
    if str(type) == 'd':
        number = ord(character) - int(shift)
        if number <= 96:
            number = ord(character) + 26 - int(shift)
    if str(type) == 'c':
        number = ord(character) + int(shift)
        if number >= 122:
            number = ord(character) - 26 + int(shift)
    character = chr(number)
    sys.stdout.write(character),

print ""
```